# What is the pthread's join prerequisite

Tags: pthreads, pthread-join

With pthread, we cannot join any thread.

What is the prerequisite and why is it there?

According to : https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html

> The pthread_join() function waits for the thread specified by
> thread to terminate.  If that thread has already terminated, then
> pthread_join() returns immediately.  The thread specified by
> thread must be joinable.

Answer (score 2):

The `pthread_join()` function makes the calling thread wait for the end of another thread (which thread identifier is passed as first parameter). By default, any thread is joinable when you call `pthread_create()`. If you want to make a thread non joinable, you can specify this behaviour by passing some attributes to the `pthread_create()` function (cf. [pthread_attr_setdetachstate()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_attr_setdetachstate.3.html)).

Comment: And any thread can detach itself or another running thread by using `pthread_detach()`.